# inclusion - different result than with direct link

Tags: php, stream

I have the following php code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
    $_GET = Array('filename' => 'scores/score.sco&scoresize=10&action=VIEW&viewtype=HTML'); // add the others here too
    include('scores.php');
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this code I'm trying to include this http://apps.facebook.com/krajecr/scores.php?filename=scores/score.sco&scoresize=10&action=VIEW&viewtype=HTML
The direct link works, but you can see the result from the inclusion here: http://apps.facebook.com/krajecr/pokus.php - `error: Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /3w/webz.cz/p/programming/facebook/scores.php on line 9`

Can you please help me solve this?

scores.php can be found here http://www.flashkit.com/tutorials/Games/High-sco-Glen_Rho-657/index.php ()

here are the first 10 lines:

```
<?php

    $winscore = (int)$winscore;

    // Create a Blank File if it doesn't already exist
    if (!file_exists($filename))
    {
        $file=fopen($filename, "w");
        fclose ($file);
    }
```

Comment: What are the contents of 'scores.php'? Also please post the error in the question rather than relying on external sites that may change/disappear.

Comment: Yea, we need a lot more than that buddy. What is `$file`? The problem is that it's not what `fclose` expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you're trying to do `fclose` on something that's not a stream resource.

Assuming you got `$file` from `fopen`, the only scenario here is that the `fopen` failed so that `$file` is [not a stream resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), but `FALSE`. It might fail if, for example, the user that your webserver is running as does not have permissions to create the file.

Add error checking to your function calls.

I can't explain why this would be different when you have PHP do the inclusion request over the web.

**Edit**

```
$_GET = Array('filename' => 'scores/score.sco&scoresize=10&action=VIEW&viewtype=HTML'); // add the others here too
```

should be

```
$_GET = Array(
    'filename'  => 'scores/score.sco',
    'scoresize' => '10',
    'action'    => 'VIEW',
    'viewtype'  => 'HTML'
);
```

Quit trying to use HTTP querystring syntax absolutely *everywhere*; that's not how the world works!

I also notice that "scores.php" never seems to define what `$filename` is. No wonder the file creation is failing: you never give it a valid filename to create! Checking the return value of `fopen` — as you always should — would have revealed this error.

You probably meant to write `$_GET['filename']`.

Comment: the file exists, if you mean scores/score.sco

Comment: ok, thanks. I changed all $filename s to 'scores/score.sco' and it kind of works now

Comment: @Tom83B: That was not my recommended fix. But glad to hear you got it working.